# check if user is signed into a Google web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cookies, google-apps

Is there a general cookie or some other way I can check to see if a user is logged into a google app. Then, if so, I'd like to run some js.
I can read the cookie and its value if I knew what the cookie is called that is generally used across google apps / services.

How can I check if a user is logged in with their google account somewhere?

What i'd like to do is if they are logged in somewhere else with their google account then sign them in automatically with that same google account.

I know how to trigger the sign in with the api:

```
var additionalParams = {
    'callback': signinCallback
};
gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams);
```

on thing I noticed on my site is that if the user is logged in with google, the cookie `G_USERSTATE_H2` has the value of `102396840558603333029=1` and I tried checking if the cookie is that value then automatically sign in using the method above, but that just opens the login window popup and then immediately closes it. I think this is because this is the cookie only for my site. What is the cookie generally used by Google for when logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons you can't go fishing around in someone else's browser cookie stash to see what they are or aren't logged into.

Using the oauth 2.0 login API (https://developers.google.com/accounts/) requires the user's explicit approval - so you won't be able to automatically do it as you are suggesting as far as I am aware.